# Как лучше реализовать Аутентификацию по номеру телефона

Tags: java, android, mysql, аутентификация

**Есть клиент на java - android приложение**

**Есть сервер на Java - работает на вебсокетах с подключенной бд**

Авторизация происходит **только по номеру**

Сейчас реализован такой подход:

1. Клиент получает номер телефона от пользователя и отправляет его на сервер
2. Сервер принимает номер, генерирует шестизначный код, получает текущее время с прибавкой 3 минуты, добавляет в базу данных в отдельную таблицу для OTP: номер, код, время. И отправляет код через смс пользователю.
3. Пользователь вводит код - код и номер отправляется на сервер - сервер ищет в бд номер и получает код из бд - сервер производит сравнение и если код совпадает и не просрочен отправляет клиенту int 0.
4. Клиент получает значение от сервера, если оно = 0 то аутентификация произошла, если нет - то ошибка.

**На сколько эта система грамотна?**

Недавно наткнулся на [статью](https://habr.com/ru/articles/305694/) в которой которой предлагают использовать TOTP или HOTP.
Я подумал, если и использовать, то TOTP чтобы было время жизни кода.
Говорят что это защита от брутфорса, но я не совсем понимаю как это работает. Нужно ли это вообще для смс аутентификации?